# Combining mesh on the fly without using gameObject

Tags: unity, c#

I procedurally generate chunks and use the marching cube algorithm to create meshes in 3D.
At first, I just created a gameObject for each cube (of course, I knew it was not optimized, but I wanted to see if the algorithm worked).
For now I stock all gamesObject in child of "blocks" but it would be much more optimized to directly merge the meshes between them and only create a single gameObject.
However, i did not find any way to directly merge the meshes between them.
So my question is: is there a way to directly merge meshes between them without having to use gameObject? (don't worry about texturing)

Here's the code:

```cs
    public static GameObject GenerateChunk(int[,,] map, int chunkSize, Vector3 chunkPosition)
    {
        GameObject blocks = new GameObject("BlockList");
        GameObject newMesh;
        int[] cubeVertices = new int[8];


        // create each mesh in a gameObject as child of "blocks"
        for (int x = 0; x < chunkSize; x++)
            for (int z = 0; z < chunkSize; z++)
                for (int y = 0; y < chunkSize; y++) {
                    /*
                    define the vertices (cubeVertices)
                    */
                    Vector3 cubePosition = new Vector3(chunkPosition.x + x, chunkPosition.y + y, chunkPosition.z + z);
                    newMesh = GenerateCube(cubePosition, cubeVertices);

                    if (newMesh != null)
                        newMesh.transform.parent = blocks.transform;
                }

        //combine every children of "blocks" and delete them
        MeshFilter[] filters = blocks.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
        List<CombineInstance> combine = new List<CombineInstance>();
        for (int i = 0; i < filters.Length; i++) {
            if (filters[i].sharedMesh == null)
                continue;
            for (int j = 0; j < filters[i].sharedMesh.subMeshCount; j++) {
                CombineInstance ci = new CombineInstance
                {
                    mesh = filters[i].sharedMesh,
                    subMeshIndex = j,
                    transform = filters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix
                };
                combine.Add(ci);
            }
            Destroy(filters[i].gameObject);
        }

        //create the chunk and set the final mesh with the CombineMeshes function
        GameObject chunk = new GameObject("Chunk", typeof(MeshFilter), typeof(MeshRenderer));
        chunk.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.CombineMeshes(combine.ToArray(), true, true);
        Destroy(blocks);
        return chunk;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shown here doesn't actually depend on GameObjects - they're just serving as an expensive way for you to store a set of positions. So you could get something equivalent as follows, just using transformation matrices instead:

```
// You can assign the default Unity cube here so you have a template mesh to stamp-out.
public Mesh cubeMesh;

public static Mesh GenerateChunkMesh(int[,,] map, int chunkSize, Vector3Int chunkPosition)
{
    // Prep a list of mesh instances to stitch together.
    List<CombineInstance> instances = new List<CombineInstance>();

    // Prepare a "template" object with the attributes we want to apply to each block.
    CombineInstance instance;
    instance.mesh = cubeMesh;

    for (int x = 0; x < chunkSize; x++)
        for (int z = 0; z < chunkSize; z++)
            for (int y = 0; y < chunkSize; y++) {                    
                Vector3Int cubePosition = chunkPosition + new Vector3Int(x, y, z);

                // If this part of the map is empty, skip it without making a block.
                if(map[cubePosition.x, cubePosition.y, cubePosition.z] == 0)
                    continue;

                // Make a transformation matrix that positions the cube at this location.
                instance.transform = Matrix4x4.Translate(cubePosition);

                // Record "I want a cube at this position" in our work list.
                instances.Add(instance);
            }
        }
    }

    // Build a mesh that combines all of the requested cubes in our work list.
    var mesh = new Mesh();
    mesh.CombineMeshes(instances.ToArray(), true, true);

    return mesh;
}
```

But note that this is still rendering more geometry than you need, because you're not eliminating hidden faces. [This answer outlines how you can do that with your own mesh generation routine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/162550/39518).

Answer (score 0):

ps: This is an answer for someone using marching cubes algorithm WITHOUT using Chunks.
I tried the precedent solution for marching cubes but without chunks, and `instance.transform = Matrix4x4.Translate(cubePosition);` makes my every little cubes distanciated a bit, so to solve this, i used instead `instance.transform = transform.localToWorldMatrix;` whichi i found in the unity documentation example.
Hopes, this helps someone :)

Comment: It sounds like you have a scale applied to your cubes, so the matrix is not a pure translation.

Comment: well yeah, i made the vertexes in a way that i can specify the default step between them. will that create any probleme?

Comment: Nope, it's just a different convention than the original Q&A covered. I wanted to clarify that this has nothing to do with chunks versus no chunks, just your choice to use a different grid spacing convention.

Comment: Oh ok, you clarified to me too. i was Wrong. Thx