# Saving mesh and instance data on the GPU?

Tags: unity, 3d, instancing

I am trying to optimize drawing a large number of voxels by using GPU instancing in **Unity**.
I am currently using Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced in a script Update(), but it occurred to me that I am still sending data from the CPU to the GPU every frame, even though my voxel positions are
static.

If I can provide a guarantee that there will be no changes at all to the voxels,
is there any way to keep the mesh data and instance positions in memory on the GPU,
and avoid a CPU -> GPU bottleneck? (I found this, not sure if it is relevant https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.UploadMeshData.html)

If so, how would I instance such meshes to draw multiple copies of them? If not possible, is there any way I can better optimize drawing large numbers of identicaly meshes whose position does not change?

Comment: Instancing individual voxel cubes is not the way to get good performance from a voxel-based game. It saves you some draw call and bandwidth overhead, but does nothing for hidden face removal and overdraw. [To get good performance, you should use chunking, not instancing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/182221/39518)

Comment: Gotcha. I'll try chunking! Do you know if it's at all possible to eliminate a per-frame uploading of voxel positions?

Comment: First, profile to determine whether the position upload is truly the bottleneck in your app. It likely takes less time than rendering a chunk, so efficiencies there might not actually win you any measurable change in your framerate.

Comment: Will do, thank you!