# How to optimize rendering in a block game in Unity

Tags: unity, block-world

I'm trying to developing a simple cube game (minecraft-like, without voxel).
Player can instantiate Cube 1x1x1 in the world.
Cube have different texture max size 512x512.

When Camera look at some "big" creation (5-8000 cubes) frame rate drop (from 100fps to 20fps using my Ryzen 4600 with integrated gpu) .
To be precise, not all 5-8000 cubes are visible to Camera, so i'm wondering if occlusion culling is working...
[image]

As you can see Render.OpaqueGeometry is the "heaviest" job.

Do you have some advice, tecnique i can use to optimize it ?

Comment: You may want to [browse past Q&A about optimizing voxel rendering by grouping cubes into "chunk" meshes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=voxel+chunk), eliminating unnecessary faces, reducing overdraw, and cutting down on batches / draw calls.

Comment: For instance, this may answer your question: [Optimization of rendering of cube world](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/182214/39518). I show some [pseudocode for constructing such a chunk mesh in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/162550/39518), and there's some discussion of [further optimization of large flat regions sharing the same texture in this Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/185036/39518). Do you need help with something not covered in these existing threads?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that unity has an overhead for each gameobject in the scene. Instantiating 1000s of objects, no matter how simple, will have a cost. You are seeing why people use voxel chunks in the first place.